# Deleting swipe-able TableView Cells using Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, xcode9.3

So, I can add tasks and persist those tasks in my app. Now what I would like to do is be able to delete tasks and persist what I deleted. I am using the swipeable cell cocoa pod in order to allow the user to swipe to the left and delete items. However, my code below doesn't seem to function the way I want it to. First of, the swipe gesture isn't working and secondly if I had "task1", "task2", "task3", I can't delete task 3 but I can delete task 1 then I can delete task 3. Also, sometimes my deleted item is persisted and sometimes not. My code is below, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
class DailyTasksTableViewController: UITableViewController {

//Variables
var tasksArray = [Task]()
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
.....

extension DailyTasksTableViewController: SwipeTableViewCellDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
        guard orientation == .right else { return nil }

    let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in
        self.context.delete(self.tasksArray[indexPath.row])
        self.tasksArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        do {
            try self.context.save() 
        }catch{
            print("error saving delete \(error)")
        }
    }

    // customize the action appearance
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete-icon")

    return [deleteAction]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsOptionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> SwipeOptions {
    var options = SwipeOptions()
    options.expansionStyle = .destructive
    return options
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for "First of, the swipe gesture isn't working"

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```